# Converting Seconds to Time Format

Tags: javascript, time, strip, seconds

I am trying to find a good solution for converting seconds to time format.

I have this function which works fine for my needs so far.

```
function secondstotime(secs)
{
    var t = new Date(1970,0,1);
    t.setSeconds(secs);
    var s = t.toTimeString().substr(0,8);
    if(secs > 86399)
        s = Math.floor((t - Date.parse("1/1/70")) / 3600000) + s.substr(2);
    return s;
}

alert(secondstotime(1920));
```

So you can run this in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7Pp5z/

So this works great and works for hours etc but i am looking to strip the zeros to the left of the time. Taking the example

i want 00:32:00

to become 32:00 so it looks better that way when outputted to the browser

Can someone tell me the best way to do this or does anyone have another function they could possibly share.

Thanks

Comment: Seconds relative to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the condition below :

```
if(s.substr(0, 2) == 00)
        return s.substr(3);
```

working demo http://jsfiddle.net/7Pp5z/2/

Comment: problem with this is the time constantly changing not a set number i need it to work dynamically say http://jsfiddle.net/7Pp5z/3/

Comment: Sorry Ashok yours does work thanks here is a updated version http://jsfiddle.net/7Pp5z/4/ thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

First off you should state your question more clearly.

"Converting Seconds to Time Format"
Seconds are one way to represent duration, but some kind of reference is needed to make it relevant.

A.D., UTC, or a duration.

See
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601
for the win.

Try this in a JavaScript Console:

```
d = new Date(1920000)
Thu Jan 01 1970 01:32:00 GMT+0100 (Westeuropäische Normalzeit)
d.getUTCMinutes()
32
d.getUTCSeconds()
0
```

Comment: sorry i have a script that is constantly updating in seconds i need to convert this to a readable time format without extra zeros either side to output to the browser.

Comment: My point is: you don't need all that bad code you and responders keep making more and more obscure.
As I have shown you can directly construct a Date object based on a millisecond value.
Then you can use its various getUTC... methods to avoid locale-specific timezone issues.
The only piece I left out is padding and other formatting markup.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function to display a time string in the requested format from a given number of seconds [s]:

```
function showtime(s){
   var time = new Date(new Date('1970/1/1 00:00').setSeconds(s))
                .toTimeString().split(' ')[0].split(':');
   return (+time[0] ? time[0]+':' : '') +
          (+time[1] || +time[0]  ? time[1] +':' : '') +
           time[2];
}
```

You can find a demonstration in this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/g5t3S/).