# Show HTML5 duration time in a div in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My problem is simple:

I have the next HTML5 video:

```
<div class="video_container">
    <video id="home_explainer_placeholder" class="video_placeholder" poster="/static/images/white_background.jpg">
        <source src="/static/videos/zapyo_intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <div>Current Time : <span  id="currentTime">0</span></div>
    <div>Total time : <span id="totalTime">0</span></div>

    <div id="home_explainer_overlay" class="placeholder_overlay">
        <div class="video_overlay">
        <div class="play_control">
            <div class="play_button"></div>
            <span class="gray">Click for video</span>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="video_mute off"></div>
            <div class="video_mute on"></div>
            <div class="video_fullscreen"></div>
            <div class="video_play"></div>
            <div class="video_pause"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to get a **backwards timer** in JS which will start after I press the play button and stop if somebody presses on pause.

I have tried to do something like this in JavaScript but when I press on my play button, nothing happens ( more, the video do not work ):

```
$(function(){
    $('#currentTime').html($('#home_explainer_overlay').find('video').get(0).load());
    $('#currentTime').html($('#home_explainer_overlay').find('video').get(0).play());
})
setInterval(function(){
    $('#currentTime').html($('#home_explainer_overlay').find('video').get(0).currentTime);
    $('#totalTime').html($('#home_explainer_overlay').find('video').get(0).duration);
},500)
```

The HTML for that JS:

```
<div>Current Time : <span  id="currentTime">0</span></div>
<div>Total time : <span id="totalTime">0</span></div>
```

Any hints on how would I achieve this ? I want to mention that I don't have a solid JS background so please explain me any solution you come with.

I have verified other [simillar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380956/current-duration-time-of-html5-video) from so, but nothing worked in my case.

Comment: Do you get an error-message when pressing the button?

Comment: Nope. It just doesn't play it anymore. Just like nothing would happen

Comment: `.html()` expects a string as argument, to set a text. You're passing it a.... well, you're calling an API (`.load(), .play()`).

Comment: Besides, you really should cache your DOM access, like `var video = $('#home_explainer_overlay').find('video').get(0)` to avoid jQuery searching twice through the DOM every 500ms.

Comment: And how to change this in order to make it work ?

Comment: Why not just `$(function(){ video.play()); })` ?

Comment: Do you just tried out this answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380956/current-duration-time-of-html5-video works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading video is asynchronous so you need to tap into the event broadcasts for `canplay`, and for time you can use the `timeupdate` event.

You can also add the attributes `preload="auto"` as well as `autoplay` to the video tag itself (shown below in modified code).

### Modified example

```js
var video = $('#home_explainer_placeholder');

// on each timeupdate event we update time data:      
video.bind("timeupdate", function() {
  $('#currentTime').html(video[0].currentTime.toFixed(2));
  $('#remTime').html((video[0].duration - video[0].currentTime).toFixed(2));
  $('#totalTime').html(video[0].duration.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video_container">
    <video id="home_explainer_placeholder" class="video_placeholder" poster="/static/images/white_background.jpg" preload="auto" autoplay>
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </video>

    <div>Current Time : <span  id="currentTime">0</span></div>
    <div>Remainding Time : <span  id="remTime">0</span></div>
    <div>Total time : <span id="totalTime">0</span></div>

    <div id="home_explainer_overlay" class="placeholder_overlay">
        <div class="video_overlay">
        <div class="play_control">
            <div class="play_button"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="video_mute off"></div>
            <div class="video_mute on"></div>
            <div class="video_fullscreen"></div>
            <div class="video_play"></div>
            <div class="video_pause"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ken . What if I want to show minutes + seconds instead of just seconds at `remTime` ?

Comment: @Alexander no problem! Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417300/converting-seconds-to-time-format) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015468/convert-seconds-to-h-hr-mm-min-time-format-with-javascript) answer for the time conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what your looking for, try it out

[Link to JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tQ2CZ/1/)

```
$(function(){
$('#currentTime').html($('#video_container').find('video').get(0).load());                          
$('#currentTime').html($('#video_container').find('video').get(0).play());
})
setInterval(function(){

$('#currentTime').html($('#video_container').find('video').get(0).currentTime);
$('#totalTime').html($('#video_container').find('video').get(0).duration);
$('#RemainingTime').html($('#video_container').find('video').get(0).duration - $('#video_container').find('video').get(0).currentTime)
},500)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution from [current/duration time of html5 video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380956/current-duration-time-of-html5-video) :

```html
<div class="video_container">
    <video id="home_explainer_placeholder" class="video_placeholder" controls>
        <source src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <div>Current Time : <span  id="currentTime">0</span></div>
    <div>Total time : <span id="totalTime">0</span></div>
    <div> Remaining: <span id="remainingTime">0</span></div>
</div>
```

And some basic JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("#home_explainer_placeholder").on(
        "timeupdate", 
        function(event){
          onTrackedVideoFrame(this.currentTime, this.duration);
        });
});


function onTrackedVideoFrame(currentTime, duration){
    $("#currentTime").text(currentTime);
    $("#totalTime").text(duration);
    $("#remainingTime").text(duration-currentTime);
}
```

And here a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4cvvg4b4/3/

Comment: This is not counting anything.

Comment: works for me at the jsfiddle. -> at the end it is doing the same like Ken's answer. next time a jsfiddle / jsbin would be helpful

Answer (score -1):

```js
var video = $('#home_explainer_placeholder');

// on each timeupdate event we update time data:      
video.bind("timeupdate", function() {
  $('#currentTime').html(video[0].currentTime.toFixed(2));
  $('#remTime').html((video[0].duration - video[0].currentTime).toFixed(2));
  $('#totalTime').html(video[0].duration.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video_container">
    <video id="home_explainer_placeholder" class="video_placeholder" poster="/static/images/white_background.jpg" preload="auto" autoplay>
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </video>

    <div>Current Time : <span  id="currentTime">0</span></div>
    <div>Remainding Time : <span  id="remTime">0</span></div>
    <div>Total time : <span id="totalTime">0</span></div>

    <div id="home_explainer_overlay" class="placeholder_overlay">
        <div class="video_overlay">
        <div class="play_control">
            <div class="play_button"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="video_mute off"></div>
            <div class="video_mute on"></div>
            <div class="video_fullscreen"></div>
            <div class="video_play"></div>
            <div class="video_pause"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```